# Convert dashed stroke to a regular path using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, stroke

For example i want to convert the following shape :

[image]

to a group of paths so i get path points in all edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer it is a simple one, just follow the next steps:

1. draw a circle for example.
2. Remove `fill` color.
3. Set `stroke` color.
4. Choose dashes type from `stroke style` with the appropriate `width`
5. From the main menu click on **Path > Stroke to Path**
6. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

*[Extensions → modify path → convert to dashes](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-ModifyPath.html#Extensions-ConvertToDashes)* does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [Path -> Stroke to Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html#Stroke-To-Path) and although that would convert the shape into a single path it does give you nodes on all edges like you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to convert dashes, which get different results:

1. draw a circle, remove fill, set stroke, choose dash style, then "Path>Stroke to Path".

With this method, in the result, each dash will be a closed subpath with 4 corners, no stroke, and fill color equal to the old stroke color.

2. draw a circle, remove fill, set stroke, choose dash style, "Path>Object to Path", "Extensions>Modify Path>Convert Dashes to Path".

With this method, in the result, each dash will be a unclosed subpath with 2 endpoints, no fill, the stroke style remains the same, except the dash style will be solid.  The "Path>Object to Path" step is essential because the "Convert Dashes to Path" will not work on an object like a circle that isn't technically a path.

For my use-case, I wanted #2, but I can see situations where #1 would be preferred.